# How to use CommandButton_Click() as Variable for File Location

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get inputs from user in Module1 & Module2 (these are file locations), and trying to run a macro in Module3 using the variable information achieved in Module1 & Module2, as file location in Module3. I'm using Excel 2016 and trying to create buttons and automate the process.

Code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

a = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If a = False Then
MsgBox ("you have not selected any file")
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 9).Value = a
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

b = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If b = False Then
MsgBox ("you have not selected any file")
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(13, 9).Value = b
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Workbooks.Open a
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
Sheets("Open Orders").Select
        Range("N2:AV2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Workbooks.Open b
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Range("A2:AL2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(b).Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-108
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4616
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 3693
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2
    Range("AY16").Select
    Sheets("Open Orders").Select
    Range("F12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Not able to run     Workbooks.Open a

Comment: If you are trying to use a variable set in one sub in another sub, then `Dim` it outside of the subs.

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` at the top of all modules, you'll see that `a` in `Workbooks.Open a` is undefined. The concept at play here is *scoping*; `a` only exists within the scope of the `CommandButton1_Click` procedure. Why can't you do `Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 9).Value` though? (but first validate that there's a value there) - someone will come along here and say "easy, just make a global variable!" ...truth is, you don't need one, you're already storing the value you need on `Sheet1`: read it from there when you need it.

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 9).Value worked, but now Im not able to select the Data from worksheet.